# cakephp 1.3 save() returns true but nothing saved in the database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Running cakephp 1.3, I attempt to insert a new entry into the database, save() returns true, but nothing is saved. I cannot pick anything in the mysql logs and there are no validation errors logged either. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
function add_action(){
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->autoRender = false;

if ($this->params) {
  echo json_encode($this->params);
}

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');

$form_data = $this->params['form'];
$data = Array(
  'ActionLists' => Array(
    'name' => $form_data['action_name'],
    'creation_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'status' => 1,
    'creator' => 'admin',
    'description' => $form_data['action_description']
  )
);
$this->log($data);
if( $this->ActionList->add_action($data)){
  $this->header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
}
else{
  echo json_encode('Not worked');
}
}
```

Model:

```
 public function add_action($data){
 $this->create();
 $outcome = $this->save($data);
 $this->log($this->validationErrors); 
   if( $outcome){
     return true;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Unless you have an alias set for your model, the key in the data should match the model name, ie `ActionList` instead of `ActionLists`.

Comment: @ndm Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. Cakephp can be pretty darn confusing. I've taken over a huge code base, using this old framework, and its a complete nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

First you should run the following  for your SQL statement after save statement.

```
$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);
```

You see exact sql statement that execute during `Model` `save`.
Most probably problem in your table for insufficient length of attributes.